# Error when installing package using apt-get

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation

I have a remote linux system, with debian version: `jessie/sid`.

`uname -a` gives:

```
>uname -a
Linux hostName 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When install any package using `apt-get`, I am getting following error:

```
Preparing to unpack .../package_amd64.deb ...
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
Can't exec "insserv": No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 391.
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/package_amd64.deb (--unpack):
```

Comment: Odd you still having a jessie/sid....that should have been automatically upgraded to a stable version *I think*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getting hints from this [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sysvinit/+bug/1024658), from the answer provided by @Steve Langasek (vorlon), by creating the following file, it succeeded.

```
sudo touch /etc/init.d/.legacy-bootordering
```